# NodeJS - Filling missing dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await

I want to copy 'results' to 'final results', but I need to fill the missing dates. I write the code below, but I can't handle the issue.

```
router.get('/userstats/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const conn = await connection(dbConfig).catch(e => {}) 
    var results = await query(conn, 'SELECT * FROM historical_contract_prediction WHERE contractId = ?;', [id]).catch(console.log);
    const error = {
        "error": `This ${id} contractId does not exist! Are you lost check our documentation!`
    }

    var i = 0;
    var last = [];
    var finalResults = [];

    var len = results.length;

    x = 0;
    while(x<len) {
        last = results[x];
        if(results[x+1] == undefined) { 
            break;
        }

        var start = new Date(results[x]["date"]);
        var end = new Date(results[x+1]["date"]);

        while(start<end) {
            last["date"] = new Date(start);
            finalResults[i++] = last;
            var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
            start = new Date(newDate);
        }    
        x++;
    }

    if(results == '') res.json(error);

    res.set({ 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
    res.send( {finalResults} );
});
```

var results:

```
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-03-29T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-03-31T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-02T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-05T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-06T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-07T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    }
```

var finalResults:

```
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-03-29T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-03-31T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-03-31T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-02T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-02T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-05T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-05T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-05T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    },
    {
      "contractId": 3573365,
      "date": "2020-04-06T03:00:00.000Z",
      "concludedWeight": 1,
      "cancelledWeight": 0,
      "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
    }
```

When I use console.log inside while loop the finalResults variable gives me the right result. But when a send back it gives me theses wrong dates.

What i expected from finalResults:

```
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-03-29T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
},
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-03-30T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
},
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-03-31T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
},
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-04-01T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
},
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-04-02T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
},
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-04-03T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
},
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-04-04T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
},
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-04-05T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
},
{
  "contractId": 3573365,
  "date": "2020-04-06T03:00:00.000Z",
  "concludedWeight": 1,
  "cancelledWeight": 0,
  "calculatedStatus": "Concluded"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement async-await. I think that the wrong part is:

```
while(start<end) {
        last["date"] = new Date(start);
        finalResults[i++] = last;
        var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
        start = new Date(newDate);
    }    
    x++;
```

It executes only if the start is smaller than the end. But your console.log prints the results before the loop.

Comment: Could you implement an Async version of this loop?